# C# code to pass value of textbox created using for loop to another page

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the following C# code to populate a div using stringbuilder, I want to get the studentid of a particular student which is clicked.

```
PSC.Data.SQLDB.SQLDBHelper objReg = null;
DataSet objRegDetails = null;
try
{
    objReg = new PSC.Data.SQLDB.SQLDBHelper();
    objRegDetails = new DataSet();
    objRegDetails = objReg.ExecuteDataSet("ListConsultants", retXML);
    if (objRegDetails != null)
    {
        if (objRegDetails.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (objRegDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < objRegDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    strRep = "<div style='width :70px;height :90px; float :left ;'><div style='width :70px; height :70px; float :left ;'>";
                    strRep += "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hdcid\"  name=\"" + objRegDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CName"] + "\" value=\"" + objRegDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ConsultantId"] + "\">";
                    strRep += "<a href='a1.asp?hdcid=<%=hdcid.Value %>'>";
                    strRep += "<img src='../Images/Consultant/defaultimage.png' style='width:70px; height:70px;float:left;'></a></div>";
                    strRep +="<div style='width :70px; height :20px; float :left ;' class='pageRegText'>";
                    strRep += objRegDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CName"].ToString();
                    //Session["ConsultantId"] = objRegDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ConsultantId"].ToString();
                    strRep += "</div>";
                    strRep += "<div style='width :70px; height :20px; float :left ;'></div>";
                    strRep += "</div>";
                    divmain.InnerHtml += strRep;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception exc)
{
}
finally
{
    objRegDetails = null;
    objReg = null;
}
```

Question: How can I get the hidden field value in another page when I click the link tag?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **hidden fields** between pages, they are available ONLY in the page they reside. I think you need to study [Query Strings](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx&ei=1G_AUKKALPH64QSt-4DwDQ&usg=AFQjCNEYU5jmTmWNIOWRwr4rAc2qeRL6Zg&sig2=8csCCpg2n_-jN9fafh4ejw) and [Session States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) then you'll have a good insight about states and you can choose the best one, here it can be **Query strings** because studentID is not something credential like a password.

for example :
source page:

```
Response.Redirect("destination.aspx" + "?StudentID=" + YourStudentID);
```

and in destination page Load :

```
txtStudentIDShow.Text = Request.QueryString["StudentID"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks,I knew about Querystring and if i pass values using querystring the hackers can easily hack.Lack of security and so what i asked any other method?

Comment: I have achieved it by using passing value to javascript function and dopostback on the same cs page and from there i took the particular value to session and i have redirected from ther.

Comment: @RenjithPalavilai if you want security along with QueryStrings you can use Encryption methods, Encrypt data before sending and decrypt it on receiving with the same key used for encryption.